# Python, как найти все числа и заменить их на Decimal

Tags: python, строки

У меня есть код (строка), в котором написано: `.1 + .1 + .1`, но нужно , чтобы код был: `Decimal(".1") + Decimal(".1") + Decimal(".1")`. Как сделать такую функцию?

P.S суть с том, чтобы все числа были заключены в метод Decimal

Comment: Хм. Я же видел уже этот вопрос, куда он делся вместе с комментариями? В общем, приведите больше кода, так не очень понятно. Вы хотите в исходном коде питоновского скрипта это сделать или где?

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так:

```py
from decimal import Decimal

a = ".1 + .1 + .1"
res = sum(map(lambda x: Decimal(x), a.split("+")))
print(res)

# 0.3
```